# How to detect a Stack Overflow error in C++Builder 2010?

Tags: stack, stack-overflow, c++builder, c++builder-2010

Is there any tool included with C++Builder 2010 which can help me detect Stack Overflow errors? Or, is there any other free-to-use tool which I can use?
How can I use them?

I've never done something like this and I would appreciate a detailed answer. How do other software developers solve this kind of error?

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. In any case, I am not aware of any such tool. Why do you think you need one? You should avoid writing code that is susceptible to SO errors in the first place. A thread's stack space is finite and typically very small, no more than a few MBs at most. The main culprit of a SO error is usually writing a recursive loop that doesn't end, but other causes include writing functions with lots of input parameters or local variables, or allocating objects/arrays that are too large for the stack.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was simply interested in understanding these types of errors, and I don't believe it's off-topic because debugging tools are essential in programming. Additionally, occurrences like these can happen, so being able to detect and resolve such issues would be valuable knowledge.

Comment: The question is sensible and reasonable - but still "off topic" for StackOverflow where questions must basically require a fixed "yes/now or this is how to do it" answer rather than recommendations. For tools recommendations try asking here: https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/41-general-help/

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, that is nice to know for the next times